# Error while performing matrix multiplication in tensorflow with masks

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say `val` is a matrix of size (2, N). I need to multiply it with a mask matrix `mask` of size
`(K,K)` containing values zeros and ones at different indexes. This should output a matrix `result` of size `(N, K, K)` matrix with each submatrix of `result` along the dimension 0 to be a `(K,K)` matrix  where zeros are replaced by `val(i,1)` and ones are replaced by `val(i,2)`.

For example,

```
mask = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=tf.int32)

val = tf.constant([[3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 6], [7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 9]])
```

Then the output should be a `7 x 4 x 4` matrix like this,

```
result  = 

tf.Tensor(
[[[ 3.  7.  3.  7.]
  [ 7.  3.  3.  7.]
  [ 7.  7.  7.  3.]
  [ 3.  7.  3.  3.]]

 [[ 2.  4.  2.  4.]
  [ 4.  2.  2.  4.]
  [ 4.  4.  4.  2.]
  [ 3.  4.  3.  2.]]
          :
          :
          :
 [[ 6.  9.  6.  9.]
  [ 9.  6.  6.  9.]
  [ 9.  9.  9.  6.]
  [ 6.  9.  6.  6.]]]
```

Currently I am using a for loop to iterate over each column of val to do the following operation

`val[0,i]*mask + val[1,i]*(1-mask)`

I am looking to vectorise it to incorporate matrix multiplication capabilities of tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need explicit for loop for what you want to do with `tensorflow`.

edit: there was an error in my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

mask = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0, 1],
                    [1, 0, 0, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=tf.int32)

val = tf.constant([[3, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5, 6], [7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 1, 9]])

mask_broadcasted = tf.broadcast_to(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=0), (val.shape[1], *mask.shape))
mask_inv_broadcasted = 1 - mask_broadcasted

val_expanded = tf.expand_dims(val, axis=-1)  # Add an extra dimension to val (expand the last dimension)
val_expanded_reshaped = tf.reshape(val_expanded, (2, -1, 1, 1))

result = val_expanded_reshaped[0] * mask_inv_broadcasted + val_expanded_reshaped[1] * mask_broadcasted

print(result)
```

Comment: It is giving me an incompatible shape error.  See in the question edit

Comment: It still gives the same error

Comment: It should be working now

Comment: It still isn't working! ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [14,1,1] vs. [7,4,4] [Op:Mul]

Comment: I updated the code, I tested it this time it is working, if it is not working what tensorflow version do you have ? you could look into tf.where also

Comment: finaly :D you welcome

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking, I found an efficient way of achieving the result. It uses `tf.gather`

```
result = tf.gather(tf.transpose(val), tf.cast(mask, dtype = tf.int32), axis=1)
print(result)
```